# Reading a large amount of bytes in C# throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I have a C# application which sends more than 600,000 bytes to the server. The response from the server has more than 10,000 bytes.  The problem I have is when I read more than 10k bytes it throws an exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed b y the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size,SocketFlags socketFlags) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer) at
>   SimpleTcpClient.Main(String[] args)

My code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10000];
int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
string Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
```

Comment: It seems like the problem might be at the other end, looking at the exception message. If you can't fix it at the other end, perhaps you can read the data in chunks and concatenate it into an array before turning it into a string.

Comment: @Celada, true in C#, but in C they are defined to be *at least* 8 bit. There exist architectures where a byte is 36 bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use sockets you must anticipate that the socket might transfer fewer bytes than you expect. You must loop on the .Receive method to get the remainder of the bytes.

This is also true when you send bytes through a socket. You must check how many bytes were sent, and loop on the Send until all bytes have been sent.

This behavior is due to the network layers splitting the messages into multiple packets. If your messages are short, then you are less likely to encounter this. But you should always code for it.

With more bytes per buffer you are very likely to see the sender's message spit into multiple packets. Each read operation will receive one packet, which is only part of your message. But small buffers might also be split.